# Header view not expanding beyond safeArea SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view consisting of a list which has a header. The header has an Image and I want that image to be expanded to the sides of the screen beyond and ignoring the safeArea. However using `List` I am not able to achieve this. If I used `ScrollView` instead of `List` this implementation would be working as I want it to. What should I do to expand the HeaderView to both sides? And what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Header()) {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct Header: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .clipped()
        }
        .frame(height: 180)
    }
}
```

Comment: on iOS it should work

Comment: it doesn't. I have two grey stripes on both sides of the image.

Comment: ok, i've got it, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for width you need the geometry of parent View (width of List)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
        List {
            Section(header: Header(width: proxy.size.width)) {
                Text("Hello")
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct Header: View {
    let width: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Image("background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: self.width, height: geo.size.height)
                .clipped()
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}
```